# Adding Parallel option is failing the job in Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am new to Pig and am trying to run the following PigScript on our 5-node Hadoop cluster.
The following script gives me the set intersection of two columns in a relation

```
register '/home/workspace/Pig/setIntersecUdf.jar'; 
define Inter com.cs.pig.SetIntersection(); 
a = load '/home/pig/pig-0.12.0/input/location.txt' as (location:chararray); 
b = load '/home/pig/pig-0.12.0/input/location.txt' as (location:chararray); 
c = CROSS a,b parallel 10; 
c = DISTINCT c; 
d = Foreach c generate $0,$1,Inter($0,$1) as intersection; 
e = Filter d by intersection !='[]' parallel 10; 
e = Filter e by $0!=$1 parallel 10; 
Store e into '/home/Documents/Pig_output';
```

When I run this script without giving the 'PARALLEL' option, it runs fine. But, when I add this option, I get the following error in the tasktracker stack of the reducers and the job fails.

```
Java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: 
java.io.IOException: File /tmp/temp-10926921/tmp-1823693600/_temporary/_attempt_201401171541_0001_r_000000_0/part-r-00000 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1 at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1639) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:736) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149) at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387) at 
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:469) at 
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigGenericMapReduce.java:432) at 
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:404) at 
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:256) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:650) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:418) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) Caused by: 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/temp-10926921/tmp-1823693600/_temporary/_attempt_201401171541_0001_r_000000_0/part-r-00000 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1 at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1639) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:736) at 
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149) at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107) at 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229) at 
$Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source) at 
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at 
org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85) at 
org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62) at $Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3686) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3546) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2749) at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2989)
```

Also, the diagnostic info for the failed job comes as:

```
   # of failed Reduce Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201401171541_0001_r_000002
```

Kindly, help!

Comment: How large is your input file?

Comment: It's only 5.9 MB.The program is running very slow if I does not add 'parallel' to it. It took around 60 hrs.

Comment: How many reducers does it use when you don't specify `PARALLEL 10`? How many lines make up that 5.9 MB?

Comment: It is using only 1 reducer. Also, the file contains 321372 lines.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you are running out of disk space on your reducer.  The `CROSS` operation is very expensive, in that it writes out every possible pair of records.  You have 321,372 records, so your data will blow up by a factor of 321,372 when you use `CROSS`.

Since your data is about 6 MB, this translates to needing to write about 1.9 TB.  When you specify `PARALLEL 10`, this gets spread across 10 reducers, which presumably doesn't max out any single machine's disk space.  But without `PARALLEL 10`, Pig is defaulting to a single reducer (probably because of the small size of your input) and trying to write all of the data on that single machine.

Perhaps you could aggressively `FILTER` your results immediately after the `CROSS` so that Pig will throw most of those records away before trying to write to disk.  Or you'll need to re-think your data flow so that you don't need to use `CROSS`.

Comment: Thanks WinneNicklaus! Actually, what I want is a set intersection of two columns. For that, I have a file which contains Locations like san diego CA or san d CA. I want the third column to be an intersection of both i.e. [san, CA]. I have this file with 321,372 records and have to take a CROSS of this with itself to get two columns. Can you suggest some changes in this script?

Comment: Possibly. Post a new question about that, with all the details of your current attempt.